# How to draw clickable grid objects inside zoomable scrollview taken datas from remote json data?

Tags: ios, swift, swift2, swift3, cgrect

I want to draw **clickable** grid objects inside zoomable `scrollview` taken datas from remote `json` data my example remote `json` file data under below;

`Json` data explode means;

> *0* = Empty object not show object in view
>
> *1* = Show object with title  and background not empty object

```
[
  {
    "Base": "A",
    "Seats": "A1*0*,A2*1*,A3*1*,A4*1*,A5*0*,A6*0*"
  }, 
{
    "Base": "B",
    "Seats": "B1*1*,B2*1*,B3*1*,B4*0*,B5*0*,B6*0*,B7*1*"
  }, 
{
    "Base": "C",
    "Seats": "C1*0*,C2*0*,C3*0*,C4*0*,C5*0*,C6*0*,C7*1*,C8*1*,C9*1*,C10-C11*1*"
  }
]
```

Also i have remote `json` parsing codes i take `json` arrays to my under below arrays successfuly ;

```
var Base = [""]
var Seats = [""]
```

Will shows in my **zoomable** `scrollview` inside that `json` like under below;

```
       1   2   3   4   5   6   7    8    9    10   11 

A         A2  A3   A4           
B      B1 B2  B3               B7     
C                              C7   C8   C9   C10-C11
```

Not empty objects like an **A2,A3,A4** must be square `width` : 20 `height` : 20 with green background clickable object. When i click in my view i can change backgroud color it to like red etc..

Also C10-C11 **MUST BE** double `width`x 2 so that seats double seats.you can see comming `json` value.

**How can i do** this i try `collectionview` but dont have `zoom` feature ? I think i need to do with **`cgrect` somethings** ?

Thank you !

Comment: Still looking for a solution ?

Comment: @cire.boroguies yeah dude.

Answer (score 0):

Is your json file format fixed or can it be customised ? it does not seems well prepared for what you expect.

You don't need to have A B C section and repeat the Section name in the grid item. As in the Battleship game, the name of each cell is expressed by the column and row title. So if you can format this:

```
[{ "A":"0","1","1","1","0","0"... },{ "B":"1","1","1","0"...},{"C" : ..."0","1","1","1",**"2"**}]
```

(NB: this works only if seat can be only doubled horizontally)

Now you create two arrays : One with bases names by getting the dictionary (from the JSON) keys: 
`let bases = jsonDict.allKeys` 
and an other with all the data in it: `let seats = jsonDict`

Now you should loop twice:
First in the base array then in the seats array for each base entry.

Each time you check the value of `seats[bases[index in base loop]][index in the seat loop]` to get the value. If it is 0 you continue, if it is 1 you create a square view and add it to the scrollview. the same if it 2 with a doubled width square view.

To set the position of the square view (or rectangle if value is 2) you use the loop index. Bases are rows and seats are columns. The anchor point of the square view will be x:0 for index 0 in the seats loop and y:0 for the A base, will be `x:20 * loop index` of the seats loop and `y: 20 * loop index` of the bases loop. Width will be `value * 20` and height always 20.

And then you manage clicks and colour states in the square view itself by handling touch event on it.

Don't forget to set the contentSize of your scrollview to CGSize(width: base[0].count * 20, height: bases.count * 20

Let me know if it help.